# Please suggest most latest compiler than Turbo C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, turbo-c++

What is the latest compiler for c++. I'm using **Turbo c++**. People say that it is ancient. Please help me with this.

Comment: [GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Comment: [You heard correctly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B). I seriously can't even imagine how it's possible to still be using it these days. Where on earth did you get it from?

Comment: @Naveen: just in case you read the nonsense below, this is one of SO's absurd default "off-topic" close reasons. I don't think this question could be improved by "describing the problem and what has been done so far to solve it", but that is what 5 people have chosen to instruct you to do. Fortunately you got a decent answer despite their efforts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turbo C++ originally dates back to 1990, which is *well* before C++ was standardised. Development continued until 1994, stopped, and was then revived in 2006.

Now, 2006 isn't exactly "ancient", but a single release means limited bug fixes, and anecdotal evidence suggests that a product with such little attention paid to it is poor at satisfying the requirements of the C++ standard. That means unexpected behaviour, and non-portable code.

Still, it seems that certain educational institutions in certain countries insist upon using this software for teaching, with no clear reason.

The version after 2006's Turbo C++ is a product called [C++Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2BBuilder) which is still maintained, with a version last released just this September.

Do these products have huge differences in their basic C++ support, compared to the mainstream compilers? No.<sup>†</sup> But teaching with this software seems to be training millions of new software developers to use outdated tools without realising it, and without realising what that means. This is a great shame.

The mainstream compilers are recommended because they have an extraordinary amount of information available regarding their capabilities and flaws. You'll find that the *vast* majority of C++ software is built by one of the following toolchains:

- [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org) (or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org) on Windows)
- [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org)
- [Microsoft Visual Studio](http://www.visualstudio.com)

---

<sup><sup>†</sup> Though given its release in 2006, it's highly doubtful that Turbo C++ gives you any coherent C++11 functionality, so that's a thing. C++Builder [does support C++11](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/42275), though it's not clear how mature this support is.</sup>

Comment: C++Builder is based on Clang (for x86-64 target)

Comment: @Abyx: Yep, that's right. [In April 2013, "C++ Builder XE4" was released, which included a 64-bit Windows compiler based on CLANG 3.1. The 32-bit compiler is still based on Embarcadero's older technology.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2BBuilder#Embarcadero_C.2B.2BBuilder) I think we'd still prefer a toolchain that's _always_ and _actually_ one of those major front-ends, and an up-to-date version at that.

Comment: They use ancient tools in schools because that's what most teachers know to use. It's really sad.

Comment: @bolov: And their students take their word as gospel. :( Without intervention, it's a never-ending cycle. That's why I was glad to see this OP speak up and _ask_ about it.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me how to install these , because in case of turbo c++, we will just install in windows. And then there will be a shortcut named msDOS on the desktop. We will just click and start coding. But these softwares are different. Just now I've installed borland c++. But I cannot go to coding area in that. Help me..

Comment: @Naveen: Why did you install Borland C++? I basically just told you _not_ to do that. Pick one of the mainstream compilers, then put in some time and effort in reading the _documentation_ which explains how to get it working. This documentation is all written, in detailed form, ready for you to read and learn. It is not appropriate for you to "not bother" with that step and just ask us to do all the work for you instead! _(cont.)_

Comment: _(cont.)_ Compilers are not always IDEs (look up these two terms on Wikipedia). It sounds like you're very used to IDEs, so I would suggest Microsoft Visual Studio. Be ready: this is not going to be a quick, two minute fix. Programming is hard and you have a lot to learn, so be prepared to spend time and energy learning!

Comment: Sorry to bother you. Programming is not at all hard for me. I did almost all programs in turbo c++ only. All this compilers and other stuff are only hard. I may continue to work on turbo c++. But I just want to catch up with this fastly evolving world, that's why I would like to emerge. Ok fine. You just never mind me. It seems i have to continue to work in that old compiler or IDM or whatever

Comment: @Naveen: Huh? No, now you're _giving up_, after just a few minutes. Not a good start! You definitely should move into the real world and drop Turbo C++. You're just going to have to accept that _nothing worth doing is ever easy_, that's all.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend you to use [GNU GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), but on windows you may also use Microsoft Visual Studio or [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/). Also [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) is gaining a lot of popularity recently and is in fact very good.

Comment: Please instruct me how to install clang:)

Comment: @Naveen: Clang has documentation which explains how to install it. Read!